# Interactive editable spreadsheet in Google Docs

Tags: spreadsheet, google-docs

I have created a spreadsheet in `google docs`. The spreadsheet takes some input, calculates some results, and displays the results numerically but also as a graph.

I would like to publish this spreadsheet, so that anyone can input and get the results and the graphs. I tried the `Publish to the Web` option (from `File` Menu), but the spreadsheet becomes static (no calculations possible on new values)

I tried the `Share` option. However when choose `anyone can view` the spreadsheet is not interactive. When i choose the `anyone can edit` option the file is usable, but my concern is that if I publish this on the internet and 2 users want to calculate simultaneously based on different values it will mix things up.

Is there anyway to accomplish what I require without setting up a website or programming in Javascript? I do not need to protect any of the calculation routines, I only require that the spreadsheet starts everytime with the default settings, the edits are not saved and the spreadsheet is interactive.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you may want to publish your Google Sheet as a template. Doing so will let strangers "deploy" a copy of your spreadsheet, for their own use (and without conflicting with other web users).

[Google Docs template gallery](https://drive.google.com/templates?type=spreadsheets)

[Instructions for submitting a template](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/148817)

Caveat: Until Google adds support for publishing "new" Google Sheets as templates, you'll likely want to submit a spreadsheet in the "old" format.

Answer (score 0):

I might suggest using Protected Ranges.

https://drive.googleblog.com/2012/08/lock-down-cells-with-protected-ranges.html

Basically locked cells and you should be the only one able to manipulate the locked cells to you can freely set the page to be editable.

You can also specify the Range of cells that you wish to use when embedding. (See the publish options).

These two methods should help you with your project.